# Correct thread to perform delete, insert and fetch from/to Core Data

Tags: ios, core-data

My app connects to a webservice, performs POST from 3 different methods and inserts each of these 3 sets of data to Core Data. Everytime new data is available everything in core data gets deleted and new data is inserted. Each of these 3 methods are displayed in different `TableViewControllers`, which means more than 3 Fetches everytime each of these `TableViewControllers` are displayed.

Wrapping things up, we have 3 sets of data that are fetched from a webservice, and then i insert all these into different entities while fetching new data to display in the main `TableViewController`.

Now i am struggling with the complex relation of threads and multi-context Core Data structure. Where should i perform the insert, delete and fetch to ensure the thread safety of my application?

Comment: How much data do you have? What contexts and threads do you have currently?

Comment: @Wain Data is relatively small. Around a thousand records in each entity. NSURLSession is working with a completionhandler on the main thread. Then it calls a method to delete (which is done on the main thread NSMainQueueConcurrencyType) and insert (main thread/NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType). Then comes the fetch on the main thread and main context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In multi-context CoreData, You can have a privateQueueRootMOC and a mainQueueRootMoc, the main MOC is used to fetch data in mainThread, the private MOC is Used to update, insert and delete data in privateMOC thread.

```
privateMOC.performBlock({ () -> Void in
    //try insert, delete, update
    ....
    try privateMOC.save()
    onCompleteBlock() //fetch data in main thread use main MOC
})
```

Comment: Ok now i moved insert and delete to the perform block of private MOC and it seems to be working fine. But there is one problem, when i refresh everything (connect to webservice, delete and insert to core data) then i perform a fetch it returns nil for a few seconds. Seems like the delete is being saved on the main context before new data is inserted.

Comment: In main MOC, You should add a complete callback block after privateMOC.save(), and read data from main thread use main MOC. Or you can use NSFetchResultController in main MOC, to observe data changed in CoreData.

Answer (score 4):

Do your UI fetches on the main thread from the main context.

For your importing, don't run the session callback on the main thread, run it on any background queue. Create a new private context and set main as its parent. In the session callback use the block interface to import and save the background context and then its parent (again, using the block interface).

Comment: We had tried dispatching session callbacks on a background thread and continuing the insertion on MainThread, but we faced several issues relating to the SaveContext on the MainContext. What exactly do you mean by "use block interface to import"? I didn't quite understand you.

Comment: `NSManagedObjectContext` provides a block interface for you to submit code to be executed in a safe way

Comment: This results in the main thread being blocked and the UI being unresponsive while inserting data to core-data. I think the delete and insert should be performed on another thread. But again when i do this the data i fetch are sometimes wrong and its like the fetch is not performed completely.

Comment: My answer says to run them on a background thread and how to setup your contexts so the changes make it to the UI with minimal effort

Comment: And that is wat i exactly did. But what happens is that when the delete+insert job is taking place on the background, the fetch is happening and after the delete obviously the entities are cleared and the persistent store is empty until new data is inserted.

Comment: so you delete everything in background, save background, insert 1, save, insert 2, save ... etc ? is the change really a full replacement or are there updates to existing objects and you're deleting everything for simplicity? your question was about thread safety, not data not being on the UI, and thread safety means large updates on a background thread in a private context. the only blocking of the main context is while the changes are merged up into that context

Comment: In this way: delete 1 insert 1, delete 2 insert 2, delete 3 insert 3, and while these happen fetches are being performed on each of these entities. Do you think two persistent stores is a good way to fix this? im pretty confused

Comment: what is triggering the fetches? if you aren't saving and the fetches are happening automatically then you're working on the wrong context...